# Creating own delete method in a doubly Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to create a delete method inside of a doubly Linked List. I am having trouble, as I think that I need to have 4 cases.

1. if the list is empty
2. if the node being deleted is the head
3. if the node is the tail
4. if the node is somewhere in the middle of the list

This is the code that I have so far.

```
public void delete(Node n) {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("the list is empty");
    } else if (head != null) {
        head = n;
        Node newHead = n.next;
        newHead = head;
    } else if (n.next == null) {
        Node beforeTail = n.previous;
        beforeTail.next = null;
    } else if (n.next != null || n.previous != null) {
        Node inFront = n.previous;
        Node inBack = n.next;
        inFront.next = inBack;
        inBack.previous = inFront;
    } else {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Here is the test program:

```
 public class TestLL {
 public static void main(String[] args){ 
     /*Create a bunch of free standing nodes */ 
     Node n1= new Node(new Integer(11)); 
     Node n2= new Node(new Integer(12)); 
     Node n3= new Node(new Integer(13)); 
     Node n4= new Node(new Integer(14)); 
     Node n5= new Node(new Integer(15)); 
     Node n6= new Node(new Integer(16)); 
     Node n7= new Node(new Integer(17)); 

     /* link them */ 
     LL myLL =new LL(); 
     myLL.printList(); // prints "empty list"
     myLL.add(n1); //11 
     myLL.add(n3); //13 
     myLL.add(n5); //15 
     myLL.add(n2); //12 
     myLL.add(n7); //17 
     myLL.printList(); //should print 11, 13, 15, 12, 17; one per line 
     System.out.println(); 
     myLL.delete(n3); 
     myLL.addAfter(n4,n1); 
     myLL.printList(); //should print 11,14,15,12,17 one per line 
     System.out.println(); 
     myLL.delete(n7); 
     myLL.delete(n2); 
     myLL.printList();//should print 11,14,15 one per line 
         } 
     }
```

I am not really sure what to do at all. Also I cannot use any methods already in Java.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the way LinkedList does this already.  You may find the code is much simpler. ;)

Comment: Also, we don't know what happens, or how what happens compares to what you expect. One glaring problem is that if `head` is not `null`, that `if` statement will run, to the exclusion of everything else.

Comment: Well, I see a mess here. After the first else, `head != null` is always `true`— why do you check? Next, instead of deleting the `Node n`, you start removing the head, inserting the `node` instead. After that, you save `n.next` to a variable, and immediately overwrite it—are you sure you need to do that? The list can go on, but I believe you must draw doubly-linked list on a napkin, and model the situation; when you know which pointers go where, you'll be in a great shape to rewrite the method.

Comment: alright i see what you guys are saying. Will try to draw it out and see. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say but the LL approach looks wrong.  Generally working with an LL will not require any awareness of "nodes" as it is up to the implementation to handle all the linking details.  The code that calls should be passing in objects of it's choice.

I would expect usage of LL to look like this.

```
LL myLL = new LL();
myLL.add(new Integer(1));
myLL.add(new Integer(2));
// etc

myLL.remove(new Integer(1));
```

During a call to add a new Node (internal class to LL) would get created and appended to the end.  Remove/delete would search the LL and remove the first instance that matches the passed in object.

e.g. A rough sketch of an LL implementation.

```
class LL
{
   private Node headNode = null;

   public void add(Object item)
   {
      // construct a new node
      // iterate to the last node and add new node to the end
   }

   public boolean remove(Object item)
   {
      // starting at the head node search the list until a node with the matching item is found
      // update the node pointers to "remove" the node
   }

   class Node
   {
       Node nextNode;
       Node prevNode;
       Object item;
   }
}
```

I won't fill in the implementations as this is homework ;) but you are right in there are a few cases to handle

- List is empty
- Item is not present
- Item is in the head node
- Item is in another node

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps alot, also it is homework but the test class, the one creating the list was actually already given the way it was by the professor.